# Is there a nightly build for Erlang/OTP?

Tags: github, erlang, common-test

I am able to build Erlang from source, and also ran the tests shipped with the source followed the instructions documented at https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/Running-tests. I am seeing about 900 failures out of a total of 11000 test cases, however, the failures are not very appealing to me in terms of:

1. Is there a nightly build for Erlang/OTP showing the success rate?
2. Are they expected to fail on this platform (in my case, it's x86
   linux)?
3. If they are not known issues, how can I find out if
   there are pull requests or bug reports associated to them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are no nightly builds.
2. As far as I know, the tests *should* be passing on your machine. Perhaps something is misconfigured?
3. Pull requests are on GitHub: https://github.com/erlang/otp/pulls and there is an erlang-bugs mailing list: http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-bugs. Here is a wiki page on Erlang bug reports: https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/Bug-reports